# How can I get an object upon it's creation?

Tags: c#, oop

I would like to know how I can get an object upon it's creation. I have two classes, a class called Product, and another class called Inventory, which is a static class. 
Here's the definition of the product class:

```
public class Product
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the definition of the Inventory class:

```
public static class Inventory
{
    public static List<Product> Products { get; set; }   
}
```

What I would like to do it's the following, when an object of type Product it's created, this object should be added to the `Inventory.Products` list, so later I can query for inventory information.

I would like to be able to do something like this inside the Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Inventory.Products.Add(this);            
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

However if I use the constructor to do this I will get an `NullReferenceException`, because `Products` is not yet initialized. Where is the best place to initialize the static `Products` list?

Comment: Where do you call `Inventory.Products = new List<Product>();`? If nowhere, that's the reason for the NullRefeferenceException, you did not initialize `Products`.

Comment: What  you're getting in this object. What your debug suggests??

Comment: @RenéVogt Thank you. The problem it's indeed that. But where would be the correct way to initialize the Products property if Inventory it's an static class and can't have constructors?

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper In the object I get all of it's properties. However I don't know where to initialize the list, since Inventory it's a static class.

Comment: In c#6 you could change the declaration to `public static List<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();` creating and read-only property. In older c# versions you could create a readonly backing field and initialize it and let the getter only return that backing field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null reference isn't the `Product`, it's the list.  Simply initialize your static list before trying to use it.  Its own class' static initializer would be a good place to do that:

```
public static class Inventory
{
    public static List<Product> Products { get; set; }   

    static Inventory()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree! But not sure what he wants?  Is it the correct OOP way to handle?

Comment: David, thank you, the problem it's indeed that. However Inventory it's a static class and therefore as far as I know can't have constructors. Where would be the best place to initialize the list?

Comment: @arthur: In the *static* constructor, as demonstrated in the answer.  Did you encounter an error when you attempted this?

Comment: @David You're right. It worked after I rebuild the whole solution.Thank you very much.

Comment: Using static list is not quite thread safe, should consider some better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities to initialize a static property. You can for example use a readonly backing field:

```
public static class Inventory
{
    private static readonly List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    public static List<Product> Products { get { return products; } }
}
```

Since C# 6 you can use a readonly property instead:

```
public static class Inventory
{        
    public static List<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

Or (as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380596/5528593) already suggested) you can use a **static** constructor:

```
public static class Inventory
{        
    public static List<Product> Products { get; private set; }
    static Inventory()
    {
         Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```